# Calculate difference in positions in Azumith measurement

Tags: python, pandas, azimuth

I am working with azimuth and elevation data in a pandas dataframe. In this reference frame, measurements are specified from -180 to 180 in azimuth and 0 to 90 in elevation. My data points are hovering around the 180 degree mark so it also registers -180 sometimes because in that frame of reference, they are right next to each other.

Here is my dataframe

```
Az      El
-179.90 2.43    
179.85  2.30
179.95  2.33
-179.99 2.40    
179.98  2.63    
-179.92 2.67
```

I am trying to find the maximum distance between any value in the az column. If I look for the min and max, and find the difference I will get `359.97` even though the true largest difference should be .25.

Does anyone know an algorithm that will work?

Here is my current code:

```
def findMaxDistanceInColumn(dataframe,dimension):
    array = dataframe[dimension].to_numpy().astype(np.float)
    min = np.min(array)
    max = np.max(array)
    difference = max-min
    return difference
```

Comment: how do you get .25 from your data, can you specify the formula ?

Comment: In that reference frame -179.90 and 179.85 are only .25 apart

Comment: 179.85 + -179.90 is -0.05 right ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The azumith measurement goes from 0 to 180 in one direction and 0 to -180 in the other direction, so its a total of 360 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have reversed the calculations: you need the *lowest* absolution value on each side of the 180 split: take the minimum of the positive values, 179.85, and the maximum of the negative values, -179.90.  Now do the math:

```
neg_dist = neg_max + 180
pos_dist = 180 - pos_min
final = neg_dist + pos_dist
```

Can you finish from there?

Comment: i think you mistype = and -

Comment: How would this logic change if there's not always a negative value?

Comment: Then you need the min and max of the existing values.